# What type of installed/updated packages recommend the option to reboot

Tags: 11.10, package-management, reboot

Sometimes when updating or installing a package, Ubuntu recommends to reboot the PC. The blue circle arrow appears. What type of packages do this and why?

Comment: Running device modules, running services, CUPS X.org.. etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually only packages for kernel upgrades, video card drivers and other hardware device drivers recommend rebooting.

Comment: Those are the obvious candidates.. but even when not installing those, I get the "reboot" arrow appearing.  I (and the OP) wonder why.